# Advice for caching nested related records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activerecord, eager-loading, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have relations like this:

```rb
class Post < AbstractModel
  belongs_to: :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :votes

class Comment < AbstractModel
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes

class Vote < AbstractModel
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :post

class User < AbstractModel
  has_many :comments
  has_many :posts
  has_many :votes
```

It's more complicated, but that is the basic idea. The `posts`, `comments` and `users` tables are pretty big, and the app is noticeably slow to show Posts.

I've already implemented eager loading, but the db load of these nested records is very slow for this legacy app with a couple million records.

On the `post` template, the `comment` load, with its `votes` and `users`, is the slowest section, even though I'm using `includes` for all the dependent record eager-loading everywhere in the app.

Is there a way to cache the db lookup, and expire the cache only if the underlying dependent records change?

I can't cache the HTML very easily, because the whole app is translated into many languages.

In the first edit of this question, I was wondering if it would be quicker to store the comments, users and votes as a serialized hash in each `post`, and just update that column whenever a comment is made or voted on.

In other words, make a new column in `Post` that stores a serialization of all that post's comments, each comments' votes, each vote's users, and each comment's author (user).

```rb
class Post < AbstractModel
  serialize :comments_cache
```

The db is mysql, in case that is relevant to the speed of eager loading and query caching.

With serialization I have concerns about data corruption, but note that the serialized column is not the "source of truth", the separate records remain the source of the serialization.

I'm also wondering about Ruby's speed in serializing/deserializing the stuff for that column. But I'm convinced from Max's response that violating 1NF is not advisable.

Comment: What is your actual query? That is kind of the heart of the matter, no? Are you using `includes`?

Comment: This question has a somewhat bizarre starting point. No one in their right mind is using `serialize` in 2022 with the exception of encrypted data as databases have native JSON/JSONB columns that can be queried. Comparing the performance of using a seperate table and a JSON column is also kind of nonsensical. It depends entirely on how the data is used and how good your queries are.

Comment: What you actually should be basing your question off is if the percieved benefits of using a JSON/JSONB column is worth violating 1NF, not having normalized data, baroque queries, not being able to use ActiveRecord assocations and the lack of type support in JSON. JSON/JSONB columns are a good tool for specialized jobs like if you data that defies a normal schema or if you have to store raw json responses. Its not a replacement for good relational database design.

Comment: In this specific case what you're doing is basically a kind of cache - and that raises the question of how you want to handle cache invalidation which is a notoriously hard and also if duplicationg your data is even a good idea. Rails has built in caching and databases are actually pretty damn effective at fetching data when used correctly. This smells like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @Beartech - yes, we're using `includes`. We have Bullet installed and working, and all the queries seem pretty well optimized. The page is just so slow!

Comment: @max - thanks for all the consideration. Yes, the idea was for caching, not for JSON responses. I'm not claiming to be in my right mind! But, to flesh out the use case a bit, it's not just for the `posts show` view. The `posts` index, a page that shows a lot of posts, has to query the tables i've called `comments` `users` and `votes`, because the `post` title is derived from the `comment` with the highest `votes`. I wouldn't call it premature optimization - it's a 15 year old app...

Comment: There are known solutions to that problem like e-tag caching that don't involve duplicating big chunks of your DB data. Caching isn't a magic bullet though. I would just use a profiler and look at where the pain points are and run `explain` on the slow queries. Go for the low hanging fruit before you go for the novel approach. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Thanks Max. Can you recommend a profiler?

Comment: update: I think [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) is what i need here.